# HTML: Possible to get keyboard event data without a keyboard event?

Tags: html, keyboard

In order to get the keyboard state we can listen to "keydown" event but is it possible to interrogate the keyboard without an event?  Something like window.keyState.shiftkey?

Answer (score 0):

In 2018 I'm investigating the same thing: (re-)initialisation on acquisition of focus.

Initialisation (determination of system state) is required when the application starts. It is required every time the application recovers focus after losing it to another application, because state like NumLock can change while the application does not have focus.

As the question notes, this information can be obtains from event objects.

### There doesn't appear to be any way to *request* this information.

This requires a change to browsers. In my opinion a low impact solution 
for this and parallel situations is a general mechanism for requesting a "null event" of a specified type, eg

```
var ke = window.requestEvent("keyboard");
var me = window.requestEvent("mouse");
var te = window.requestEvent("haptic");
```

Since a keyboard/mouse/touch event is not actually occurring, the field that would otherwise quantify the event (key code, mouse position etc) should be null.

This API should not be a breaking change for event handlers, since it doesn't actually trigger an event, it's a function that returns an event object. It's completely new so there is no legacy code, and it can be extended without change simply by defining more event class strings. No new data structures are defined.

If I knew how to submit a change request to the pertinent browser standards committee, this seems to me like a very tight, robust, compatible solution to several problems. I'm recording this here as a sort of message in a bottle, in the hope that one day it will be seen by someone who can act on it.